# Why does the build in this dockerfile fail, while exact the same commands run manually succeed?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime && echo Europe/Berlin > /etc/timezone \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y git default-jdk-headless ant libcommons-lang3-java libbcprov-java \
&& git clone https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk.git \
&& cd pdftk \
&& mkdir lib \
&& ln -st lib /usr/share/java/{commons-lang3,bcprov}.jar \
&& ant jar

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/pdftk/build/jar/pdftk.jar"]
```

When building the image, it fails upon the ant step with several errors like this:

```
[javac]   symbol:   class ASN1Sequence
[javac]   location: class PdfPKCS7
[javac] /pdftk/java/pdftk/com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfPKCS7.java:282: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         BigInteger serialNumber = ((ASN1Integer)issuerAndSerialNumber.getObjectAt(1)).getValue();
```

However when starting a container manually (`docker run -it --rm ubuntu:focal`) and executing exact the same commands (Sure no typo, Copy/Pasted the whole block several times), the build succeeds.

Any idea what might be different during the docker build and a manually started container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, this one is a tricky one.

When you build the container, the program which executes your instruction set is **`shell`** (`/bin/sh`) whereas when you run `docker run -it --rm ubuntu:focal`, it is going to be run on **`bash`** (`/bin/bash`).

Basically, you manually ran all your instructions on `bash`.

The easiest solution would be to use `bash` to run your instruction set because it already works as you tested.

You can simply instruct the docker to run all your instructions on `bash` using this command at the top:

```sh
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

The changed Dockerfile will be:

```sh
FROM ubuntu:focal

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN ps -p $$
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime && echo Europe/Berlin > /etc/timezone \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y git default-jdk-headless ant libcommons-lang3-java libbcprov-java \
&& git clone https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk.git \
&& cd pdftk \
&& mkdir lib \
&& ln -st lib /usr/share/java/{commons-lang3,bcprov}.jar \
&& ant jar

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/pdftk/build/jar/pdftk.jar"]
```

Hope this helps you. Cheers  !!!

Comment: Great - Thanks! I'd never have found this.